# Norm of element of Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

How to prove that in a Hilbert space $H$,
$$\lVert h \rVert = \sup_{u \in H}\frac{|(h,u)|}{\lVert u \rVert}?$$
Showing that the RHS is $\leq$ the LHS is easy but not sure of the other part.

This is similar to definition of the norm of a bounded linear functional so there may be a link.

Comment: I think you want to exclude $u = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is exactly the norm of the functional $(h,-):u\mapsto (h,u)$.

One direction follows from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$|(x,y)|\le ||x||\cdot||y|| \ ,$$
and for the other part consider $u:=h$.